# Autodesk Forge Datamanagement API

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

We uses Autodesk Fusion Team to manage collaboration. To get an overview of users activated in the hub and get the last activity date I want to write some code.

I checked via Postman what the Datamanagement API responses, but there is no documented request to get users like it is in the BIM360 API.

https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/accounts/accountId/users
This is the request from the documentation of the BIM360 API. I'm searching for the possibility in Fusion Team.

```
[
  {
    "id": "a75e8769-621e-40b6-a524-0cffdd2f784e",
    "account_id": "9dbb160e-b904-458b-bc5c-ed184687592d",
    "status": "active",
    "role": "account_admin",
    "company_id": "28e4e819-8ab2-432c-b3fb-3a94b53a91cd",
    "company_name": "Autodesk",
    "last_sign_in": "2016-04-05T07:27:20.858Z",
    "email": "john.smith@mail.com",
    "name": "John Smith",
    "nickname": "Johnny",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "uid": "L9EBJKCGCXBB",
    "image_url": "http://static-dc.autodesk.net/etc/designs/v201412151200/autodesk/adsk-design/images/autodesk_header_logo_140x23.png",
    "address_line_1": "The Fifth Avenue",
    "address_line_2": "#301",
    "city": "New York",
    "postal_code": "10011",
    "state_or_province": "New York",
    "country": "United States",
    "phone": "(634)329-2353",
    "company": "Autodesk",
    "job_title": "Software Developer",
    "industry": "IT",
    "about_me": "Nothing here",
    "created_at": "2015-06-26T14:47:39.458Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-04-07T07:15:29.261Z"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunate there is no API for that in Fusion Team.

Comment: Hopefully Autodesk will make it possible.